# Autowire an interace which extends another interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@component
public interface A extends RootInterface{}

@Configuration
public interface RootInterface{
public String hello();
}


@Service
public class SomeClass implements RootInterface{}


public class RandomClass{
@Autowired
A a;
}
```

implementing a flow like this throws a error

> Field a in com.package.RandomClass required a bean of type
> 'com.package.A' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.package.A' in your
> configuration.

Comment: can you add stacktrace?

Comment: This error is showed while app is starting, there is no stacktrace

Comment: it looks like you are trying to inject bean of type `Sample` but you have not prepared that bean

Comment: @VeKe there was a typo, can you please look into the error and tell me again

Comment: com.package.A can you show this class

Comment: I just wote it as mentioned above

Comment: Do you have implementation for interface A?

Comment: No direct implementation

Comment: you need a implementation, Spring try to create and inject a object

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with this code. However, the reason why you are getting this exception is that you have not implemented interface A. And if you have implemented interface A but you have missed it in the question then the reasons could be that you have not annotated your implementation properly or you have restricted the scanning scope.

Comment: that is the entire project I didn;t missed anything, can you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Create a class and implement interface A. Mark this implementation with an appropriate annotation like component, service, etc. so that the component scan can find and create a bean for the same.